# Weight by price- Grocery

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-options

If in some product price varies based on weight like [kiranaman.com](http://www.kiranaman.com/grocery-staples/atta-flours/wheat-atta/whole-wheat-atta.html?sid=827) or [truemart.in](http://truemart.in/fresh-fruits-and-vegetables/fresh-vegetables/American%20Corn%20Cob%20-%20Butta%20Whole%20Cleaned) > grocery having an option for display weight, so like same way anyone please suggest me how this works for my store. I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2 version. Please find out the URLs and image

`Display Weight        Actual Weight    Price     Spl. Price
  20 Lb  (9.08 Kg)        20 Lb         $15.99

  10 Lb (4.54 Kg)         10 Lb          $8.99      $8.49
   5 Lb (2.27 Kg)          5 Lb          $5.99

   2 Lb (908 g)            2 Lb          $2.99

   1 Lb (454 g)            1 Lb          $1.49`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do your variants (in your case, the various weight options) have differnt SKUs?
If you have different SKUs, you should go for configurable products.
If you just have a different price depending on the selected weight but still the same SKU, you should go for products options instead.